How to look through the errors that MediaWiki's update.php is reporting?
I'm currently updating my MediaWiki from 1.27 to 1.35.
As the instruction says, I'm running the maintenance/update.php script.
During the process, I'm receiving some messages about the errors, e.g.:
Completed migration, updated 1836 row(s) with 0 new actor(s), 12372 error(s)

And that's not the only one, there is around 5 similar messages popping up.
Is there a log where a can look into those errors? The output of update.php is 1300 lines long and it doesn't contain any info about so many errors (approx. 20000 in total), only the ones on the matter of users with no ID.

Possibly https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Log or https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug are relevant?

Or just look in the normal PHP error log?
